# How do I bring a value out of a function?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def xdgt(x):
    if x is "m":
        a = True
        print(a)
    else:
        a = False
        print(a)

x = input("Are you Male or Female? please only input m or f:")    
xdgt(x)
print(a)
```

---

**Result:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/tmp/sessions/dd8fb527f68c80d1/main.py", line 10, in 
>       print(a) NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Its hard to comment without knowing how you have formatted your python code.

Comment: Don’t use `is` to compare strings, use `==`. In short, your function should be written as `return x == 'm'`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to use local variable a outside of the function, use `global`.

```
def xdgt(x):
    global a
    if x == 'm':
        a = True
    else:
        a = False

x = input("Are you Male or Female? please only input m or f:")

xdgt(x)

print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `return a` to your function

```
def xdgt(x):

  if x is "m":

    a = True

  else:

    a = False
  return a
```

```
a = xdgt(x)
print(a)
```

Comment: Precisely to the point, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the function to return the value. In which case you can change your code as follows:

```
def xdgt(x):
    if x is "m":
        a = True
    else:
        a = False
    return a

x = input("Are you Male or Female? please only input m or f:")

return_val= xdgt(x)
print(return_val)
```

**Takeaway here:**

Instead of printing the value inside the function you should return it and store it in a variable so that you can use it to perform functions you desire like printing the value in this case.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I need. Thank you